# Get url-pattern from servlet-name

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml, url-pattern

I have this configuration in web.xml fileof my Java EE Web application:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ChangeLanguageServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/change</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I want to do is get the String of "url-pattern" using the servlet-name,  something like this (pseudocode):

```
// This would return "/change"
String pattern = getPatternByServletName("ChangeLanguageServlet");
```

I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) you can get a `Map` keyed by servlet name with all servlets registered in the application:

```java
Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> registrations = 
        servletContext.getServletRegistrations();
```

Then use the [`ServletRegistration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html) API to extract the metadata you need, including:

- [Servlet name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Registration.html#getName--)
- [Servlet class name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Registration.html#getClassName--)
- [Servlet mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#getMappings--)
- [Servlet initialization parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Registration.html#getInitParameters--)

Comment: `ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();` I think this was missing